# Segmentation fault; Trying to convert int to binary in C

Tags: c, arrays, binary, syntax-error

I'm trying to convert an integer into binary using this method:

```
int * intToBinary(int i) {
//return value
   int binary[] = {'\0'};
   int index = 0;

   for (int x = i; x != 0; x /= 2) {
       binary[index] = x%2;
       index++;
   }   

   return binary;
}
```

The idea is that I would reverse the array (because that would be the right answer) and I would get the conversion. I already tried doing this in Python and it worked beautifully.

The problem: When I run the above method I get a `Segmentation Fault: 11` error. I know it usually happens if I use an int that is out of index for the array, but that doesn't look like the problem. Does anyone have any idea as to why I keep getting this error?

Comment: How big do you expect `int binary[] = {'\0'};` to be?

Comment: a) You need to allocate room for the 'binary' array. b) You cannot return the address of a stack allocated variable.

Comment: that's not even all to it, this local array has **only 1 element**, so ub already during function execution (out of bounds access)

Comment: If you're building a string, here are some other problems: 1) `x%2` should be `(x%2) ? '1' : '0'`. 2) You need to append a NUL (`'\0'`) to it. 3) You are storing the bits in the reverse of the usual order.

Comment: If you're really are building an array of numbers, here are some other problems: 1) The caller need to know how big the returned array is. 2) No reason to use an `int` instead of `char` when the only possible values are `0` and `1`.

Comment: arrays do not dynamically resize in `c`. You need to initially declare them with the size you want, or allocate memory during runtime with `malloc` and friends.

Comment: Note: `binary[index] = x%2;` results in `binary[index]` having a value of 0,1 or -1.  More like a trinary than binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *two* problems, both leading to *undefined behavior*.

The first is that you return a pointer to the local array `binary`. That array will cease to exist once the function have returned, leaving you with a stray pointer. This probably isn't what's causing the crash though.

What is the most likely reason for the crash is that the array `binary` only has ***one*** element. That means your loop will write out of bounds of it. For 32-bit integers it needs to contain 32 elements.

The second problem is easy to fix, just set the correct size. The first problem is a bit harder, but my suggestion is that you create the array in the *calling* function, and pass it in as an argument.